Javasrcript/Vue.js: Module not found (@supabase/supabase.js)
I'm trying to connect with supabase from Vue.js 3-rd verstion UI. But when I start my project with npm run serve, I'm getting the following error:

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@supabase/supabase.js' in '/Users/alexandr/Documents/Other Projects/Vue3/004/servers/src'


Error tells that it could not find module in .../servers/src but all modules in node_modules, which is in main project's location.

In src folder only vue components, js-file and css theme.

Here is my code of main vue.js file
<template>
  <div class="container">
  </div> 
</template>

<script>
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase.js'

export default {
  methods: {
    async loadPeople() {
      const supabaseUrl = process.env.SUPABASE_URL
      const supabaseKey = process.env.SUPABASE_KEY

      const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey)

      console.log('Supabase Object\n\n', supabase)

      const {data, error} = await supabase.from('Customers').select('*')

      if (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }else{
        console.log('data\n\n', data)
      }
      
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>


npm@10.9.2
@vue/cli 5.0.8
@supabase/supabase-js@2.47.9
npm run serve starts the following cmd vue-cli-service serve
Firstly, I've reinstalled subabase like npm install @supabase/supabase-js instead of 'npm install supabase'. But it did not helped.
I can't understand why js searching module in src instead of Project/node_modules?
